# Pymongo Check if record exists, if not, then insert, on the basis of column which is the unique key

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am using python to update the data in my MongoDB database.
I want to insert the data frame rows only if it does not already exist in the Database. I want to check the existence of the record using only one column- variant_id (unique key). The variant_id which are already present in the database, should not get modified. Only the new variant_id should be getting appended.

Original Database Table-

[image]

New Dataframe to be inserted-

[image]

Database Table After Insertion-

[image]

Comment: When you write "Table", do you mean "collection" or "document"?  I.e., does your collection consist of documents with three fields? ... or are you showing a single document that has an array of objects where each object has three fields?

Answer (score 0):

try this did you means this?

```
db = client['testdata']
testCollection = db['collectionName']

df =  pd.DataFrame(list(testCollection.find({})))
df.info()


def insert_data(df):
    meta = df.to_dict('records')
    testCollection.insert_many(meta)

if df.empty:
    insert_data(ji10001)
```